# meteorjs - spiderable & phantomjs for seo

Tags: javascript, meteor, phantomjs

Tried to install spiderable and phantomjs for SEO.

The first was that i added spiderable.

```
meteor add spiderable
```

Works fine. Installed. When i try to open a url with the GET parameter like `http://localhost:3000/?_escaped_fragment_=` there is a server error - phantomjs is missing.

So i added phantomjs smart package.

```
mrt add phantomjs
```

When I reopen my project url with the GET paramter there is no Server error and no client JS error. But the Source-code of this website is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html class=" js cssanimations csstransitions"><head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/1c2c36f3a0bb39970171882896d7e916b597a938.css">



[A feeeeeew breaks! About 150 breaks - dunno why.]


<title>My title</title>
    </head></html>
```

So the website is just white. No content in it.

Tried a few parameter and also empty parameter.

For example:
in iron-router i setuped the /jobs path. So i tried:

```
http://localhost:3000/?_escaped_fragment_=jobs
```

iron-router uses for jobs a plain HTML template. No helpers or smth else. Just to test the spiderable package.

No errors - not on client and not on server. Something missing ? Dunno whats wrong with my code. I also used this list: http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/spiderable

The troubleshooting ... all in this list is fine.

**Info**:
I still installed phantomjs on my OS too!

```
 $ phantomjs -v // returns 1.9.7
```

Comment: what is your actual question? If you are seeing HTML that is different from what you are expecting, then it would of you could tell us what you were expecting and what the templates were you used to render it. Otherwise I don't know how to help. As you can tell, I'm not the only one who thought you were asking about the correct way of installing phantomjs and getting it to work.

Comment: I think that i installed phantomjs the rigth way. Its installed on my OS and also as a smart package in my App. I followed the troubleshooting points in the link I given in my question. My test template which has to be rendered is plain HTML - jo JS is given in it like Helpers or other methods for the template. What i am expecting to get ? Of course the HTML from the plain HTML template which has to be rendered.

Comment: localhost:3000/jobs renders everything fine - but its importent to make it readable for google.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What is the plain HTML template? You never showed that to us.

Comment: Just plain html. <template name="jobs"><h1>Welcome to our jobs.</h1></template> Plain HTML without any Helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I see missing is the lack of the `<meta>` tag. In the head of the document there should be

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

Look at Manuel Shoebel's blog it might help.

http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteor-and-seo

Comment: When i defaulz loading a page like localhost:3000/jobs the tag isnt missing - its still there. Just when i use the get-parameter

Comment: I just tested and `http://localhost:3000/?_escaped_fragment_=` doesn't make the meta tag go away. I don't have phantonjs installed either. Hope it helps

Comment: U just gave me the right answer... i am an idiot. I just used it wrong. I used it this way: http://localhost:3000/?_escaped_fragment_=jobs and not http://localhost:3000/jobs?_escaped_fragment_=.

Comment: But i am wondering ... i just thought that google will read it in the way i just did it, isnt it ? A bit strange ...

Comment: I don't think so. It seems that the purpose of the meta tag is precisely to know where to stop and ask for the request of that particular url. But I'm no where near to understand this, so yeah, just weird :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mrt remove phantomjs
npm install -g phantomjs
```

Comment: phantomjs is still installed on my OS. "phantomjs -v" returns 1.9.7

Comment: I'm pretty sure `spiderable` requires the phantomjs NPM module to be installed.

Comment: Thats right. Its also in the checklist for troubleshooting. I still installed phantomjs with npm

Answer (score 0):

The usual culprit is that spiderable may be waiting for some subscriptions to finish returning data, whereas those subscriptions actually aren't sending data at all. You'll need to look into the packages you are using in your project as well as your code to see what might be the culprit. Another reason may be that PhantomJS isn't able to connect to your server, which often happens if you are running behind a load-balancing reverse proxy.

How long does testing with `?_escaped_fragment` take for the page to load? This will allow you to distinguish between the two situations.

For other possible causes, check out the following leads:

- https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1992
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/9AHQt2zdUQ8

In my experience, one package that caused these errors was [Observatory](https://github.com/jhoxray/observatory).

Comment: quick answer: The page load takes about 1 second or less. Later I willl follow your external links

Comment: The Chrome console returns this for the pending time of loading the page: ?_escaped_fragment_=jobs  GET  200OK  text/html Other  919 B  1.64 s